# @Async vs. Reactor thread pool in Spring

Tags: multithreading, spring, spring-annotations, reactor

What is the difference between [@Async](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/scheduling.html) annotated method and [Reactor](http://spring.io/blog/2013/05/13/reactor-a-foundation-for-asynchronous-applications-on-the-jvm) set to use thread pool of the same size. Is there any advantage to one of this methods and what it would be? For my use, I do not care to return any value with the asynced method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most obvious difference is that Reactor doesn't crosscut `@Async` annotated methods and implicitly submit events to a `Reactor`. If you're using the Reactor `@Selector` annotation on beans then you're getting the opposite of what you would with `@Async`: an event *handler*, not an event *publisher*.

With that said, there is some support in Reactor for `@Async`-style event publishing through the [DynamicReactorFactory](http://reactor.github.io/docs/api/reactor/core/dynamic/DynamicReactorFactory.html). It uses an interface instead of an annotation, but the concept is similar.

Regarding "advantages" to using one or the other: it really depends on what other things you're doing in your application and whether or not you're using Reactor in a more general sense. Reactor isn't designed to be a thread pool replacement. The `ThreadPoolExecutorDispatcher` in Reactor just uses a plain `ThreadPoolExecutor` underneath. The advantages to using Reactor in that scenario come from the optimized event publishing used in Reactor versus creating new `Callables` and `Runnables` all the time, as well as using Reactor's `Stream` and `Promise` API to handle asynchronous execution.

Looked at from the API prespective, there is a distinct and measurable advantage to using Reactor over a plain `TaskExecutor` for background jobs.